# Ping a Container within "Docker in Docker"

Tags: docker, routes, iptables

I know it's a little bit strange setup.
I create two containers con1 and con2. con2 is extended from docker:dind which allows me to run docker containers within a docker container. The container which is running within con2 is named internal_container. Now I try to ping this internal_container from con1.
I think this should be possible by a special iptables rules but I'm not familiar with iptables maybe someone an idea?

```
#!/bin/bash

docker rm -f con1
docker rm -f con2
docker network rm net1

docker network create \
  --driver=bridge \
  --subnet=172.28.0.0/16 \
  --ip-range=172.28.5.0/24 \
  --gateway=172.28.5.254 \
  net1

docker run -itd --network=net1 --ip=172.28.5.1 --privileged --name con1 ubuntu
docker exec con1 apt-get update 
docker exec con1 apt-get install -y iptables iputils-ping
docker exec con1 sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1

docker run -itd --network=net1 --ip=172.28.5.2 --privileged --name con2 docker:dind
sleep 2 # Wait until docker deamon is up

# Create a network within "docker in docker"
docker exec con2 \
    docker network create \
        --driver=bridge \
        --subnet=172.28.6.0/24 \
        --ip-range=172.28.6.0/24 \
        --gateway=172.28.6.254 \
        dind_net

# In this "docker in docker" container create a container and join it to the dind_net network
docker exec con2 \
    docker run -itd --network=dind_net --ip=172.28.6.1 --name internal_container busybox
docker exec con2 sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1

# Ping the internal_container(within the "docker in docker" container)
docker exec con1 ping 172.28.6.1
```

[image]